# extract annotated text from text file by using java code

Tags: java, annotations, gate

I have annotated text file on the following format:

```
<paragraph><weakness>Buffer</weakness> <weakness>Overflow</weakness>
in <location>client/mysql.cc</location> in <application>Oracle</application> 
<application>MySQL</application> and <application>MariaDB</application> 
<version>before</version> <version>5.2</version> <vulnerability>allows
</vulnerability> <vulnerability>remote</vulnerability> 
<application>database</application> <application>servers</application> 
...
...
```

What I would like to do is to create a Java code to parse the above text file and put it in the following format:

```
Buffer  weakness
overflow  weakness
in   O <--- 'O' means doesn't have annotation
Oracle  application
MySQL   application
...
...
```

I tried to tokenize the file, but the problem is, I will do parsing and formatting again, and I could lose some useful information!!

Please any help !!

Comment: youve tagged the question "gate" - does that mean the file you've described was created using GATE, and do you want an answer to create your target format directly from the GATE document?

Comment: Alternatively, if the file really is XML (rather than text that happens to contain angle brackets, i.e. it is well formed with all `&` escaped as `&amp;` etc) then this conversion would be simple with an XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Yes, the file that I've described was created using GATE, after manual tagging I saved the file by clicking "Saved Preserving Format" option. 
So, the file that I got is not xml while the annotated words were tagged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some XML Parsers that can parse your xml : eg: [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/) , [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/)

Also you can use the [Java Xpath Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) provided in JDK version 1.5 and higher to extract the contents from XML if you know the XPATH for the elements that you are looking for. For eg : For extracting all weakness, you can just use the following XPATH : `/paragraph/weakness`

Choose the library that suits your purpose the most.

Comment: But the problem with XML Parsers I can't extract un-annotated words from the text !! 
I tried with JSOUP ...

Comment: Can you point me which data in your XML is not getting processed ?

Comment: for example, the data that is not tagged; from the question above you will realize some words such as "in" doesn't have tag so, So I need it on the results and I will assign "O" to it for post processing ...

Comment: In this case you have no option but to process the XML file from start to end and look for '<' & '>' tags and extract elements, just like what XML Parsers do. With the exception that you will also be looking for un-annotated words.

Answer (score 0):

Split your text by spaces into a String array, then for each strings in the array, look after a "<" sign, if found, then parse it with Xpath, else write out the value and 0, as you need to.

```
...
String split[] = readLine.split("\\s");
for (String string : split) {
  if (string.indexOf("<") != -1) {
    //XPath parsing
  } else {
    System.out.println(string + " O");
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is indeed well-formed XML (with balanced tags, all `&` characters escaped as `&amp;`, etc.) then this is pretty straightforward with an XSLT 2.0 transformation

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <!-- ignore text nodes that are _entirely_ whitespace -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//paragraph//text()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <!-- name of the element that contains this text node -->
    <xsl:param name="tag" select="local-name(..)"/>
    <!-- for each word in the text node -->
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(), ' ')">
      <!-- word-TAB-tag-NL -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#9;', $tag, '&#10;')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special case for nodes directly under <paragraph> - use "O" -->
  <xsl:template match="paragraph/text()">
    <xsl:next-match>
      <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="'O'" />
    </xsl:next-match>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can run this from Java using [Saxon 9 HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net).